# How to show up Detection result on Tensorboard using tflite_model_maker

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tensorflow-lite

```py
    #tensorflow = 2.6.0  
    #tflite_model_maker = 0.3.2  
    #Python = 3.7.11 (on colab)

    # load model spec
    spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0')
    
    # adjust model_spec's config for Tensorboard
    setattr(spec.config, "sample_image", "/content/data2/IMG_0187.JPG")
    setattr(spec.config, "profile", True)
    setattr(spec.config, "img_summary_steps", 1) # default value is None
    
    # Do train!
    model = object_detector.create(train_data,                               
                                   model_spec=spec,
                                   batch_size=8,
                                   train_whole_model=False,
                                   epochs = 100,
                                   validation_data = valid,
                                   do_train = True)
    
    model.evaluate(test)
```

I think "img_summary_steps" option is for detected results visualization per 1epoch on Tensorboard
but when i use "img_summary_steps" occurred error :<

training well when i don't use "img_summary_steps" option but not show up Detection result on Tensorboard

this is result when i print(spec.config)

```
    act_type: relu6
    alpha: 0.25
    anchor_scale: 3.0
    apply_bn_for_resampling: true
    aspect_ratios:
    - 1.0
    - 2.0
    - 0.5
    autoaugment_policy: null
    backbone_config: null
    backbone_name: efficientnet-lite0
    batch_size: 64
    box_class_repeats: 3
    box_loss_weight: 50.0
    ckpt_var_scope: null
    clip_gradients_norm: 10.0
    conv_after_downsample: false
    conv_bn_act_pattern: false
    data_format: channels_last
    dataset_type: null
    debug: false
    delta: 0.1
    drop_remainder: true
    first_lr_drop_epoch: 200.0
    fpn_cell_repeats: 3
    fpn_config: null
    fpn_name: null
    fpn_num_filters: 64
    fpn_weight_method: sum
    gamma: 1.5
    grad_checkpoint: false
    grid_mask: false
    heads:
    - object_detection
    image_size: !!python/tuple
    - 320
    - 320
    img_summary_steps: null
    input_rand_hflip: true
    iou_loss_type: null
    iou_loss_weight: 1.0
    is_training_bn: true
    jitter_max: 2.0
    jitter_min: 0.1
    label_map: null
    label_smoothing: 0.0
    learning_rate: 0.08
    loss_scale: null
    lr_decay_method: cosine
    lr_warmup_epoch: 1.0
    lr_warmup_init: 0.008
    map_freq: 5
    max_instances_per_image: 100
    max_level: 7
    mean_rgb: 127.0
    min_level: 3
    mixed_precision: false
    model_dir: /tmp/tmpaziqa0l2
    model_name: efficientdet-lite0
    model_optimizations: {}
    momentum: 0.9
    moving_average_decay: 0
    name: efficientdet-lite0
    nms_configs:
        iou_thresh: null
        max_nms_inputs: 0
        max_output_size: 100
        method: gaussian
        pyfunc: false
        score_thresh: 0.0
        sigma: null
    num_classes: 90
    num_epochs: 50
    num_scales: 3
    optimizer: sgd
    poly_lr_power: 0.9
    positives_momentum: null
    profile: false
    regenerate_source_id: false
    sample_image: null
    save_freq: epoch
    scale_range: false
    second_lr_drop_epoch: 250.0
    seg_num_classes: 3
    separable_conv: true
    skip_crowd_during_training: true
    skip_mismatch: true
    stddev_rgb: 128.0
    steps_per_execution: 1
    strategy: null
    survival_prob: null
    target_size: null
    tf_random_seed: 111111
    tflite_max_detections: 25
    use_keras_model: true
    var_freeze_expr: (efficientnet|fpn_cells|resample_p6)
    verbose: 0
    weight_decay: 4.0e-05
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f7wN.png)